# Selenium Chromedriver - Click Cancel Chrome Authentication Pop Up

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using a VPN Chrome app for a python application. Whenever I start up a Chrome instance and Chrome starts to load a website before the VPN addon is ready, the following pop-up appears. As soon as I hit the cancel button, the VPN addon is usually ready and I can access the internet without issues.

I'm looking for a way to click the Cancel button with Selenium.

What I have tried so far:

- Set the home page to Chrome Settings -> pop-up doesn't appear because settings are not a website, after a short time.sleep, I can proceed without issues most of the time. Every once in a while, the pop-up still appears.
- Using `webdriver.ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE).perform()`
  Whenever I try this, the script freezes, until I hit the Cancel button manually, then the action is executed. The same happens with `driver.get(url)`and `driver.switch_to.alert()`

Thanks!

[image: Screenshot]

Edit 1 (Setting Chrome options to not show notifications and infobars doesn't resolve the issue):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import selenium.common.exceptions

options = Options()
options.headless = False

options.add_argument("user-data-dir=ChromeProfiles\Profile_{}".format(22))
options.add_argument("--profile-directory=profile_1")
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path="chromedriver.exe")
```

As you can see, commands are not executed as long as the popup is open:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have tried chrome options to disable pop up notification?

Comment: I tried using ```prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2} ``` and ```options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs) ```  without results.

Comment: I had a similar problem some months ago using ChromeDriver. But when i changed it to run on a FireFox Browser, using driver.switch_to.alert(), it worked fine. Can you test if the same occurs in Firefox, using `driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss()`?

Comment: I just checked out Firefox + Geckodriver. Unfortunately it seems like there are some issues with Firefox when it comes to loading custom profiles, which I rely on for my project.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Hi Martin, unfortunately, I did not.

Answer (score 2):

1) void dismiss() // To click on the 'Cancel' button of the alert.

```
driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();
```

2) void accept() // To click on the 'OK' button of the alert.

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

3) String getText() // To capture the alert message.

```
driver.switchTo().alert().getText();
```

4) void sendKeys(String stringToSend) // To send some data to alert box.

```
driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys("Text");
```

You can reference all this from [Guru 99](https://www.guru99.com/alert-popup-handling-selenium.html)

Also you should look at which kind of alert it is, browser push notification, browser alert, etc...

These are my chrome options to disable notifications, alerts, and push notifications

```
chrome.switches = --incognito;--disable-download-notification;--disable-infobars
```

Also another way to implement chrome options

```
ChromeOptions ops = new ChromeOptions();
        ops.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
        ops.addArguments("--disable-infobars");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./lib/chromedriver");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(ops);
```

Lastly here are the chrome driver docs to help you further.
[ChromeDriver Docs](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities)

Edit:

```
driver.switchTo().activeElement();
driver.close()
```

Or you can try

```
Driver.SwitchTo().frame("NameOfFrame");

Driver.findElement("enter path to cancel button").click();

Driver.SwitchTo().defaultContent();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: ```driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss()``` doesn't do anything until I manually click on cancel, like I said in my post. I also tried setting the Chrome options like you pointed out at the end of your post. Unfortunately, the pop up isn't surpressed this way. It still shows up.

Comment: Is this a browser level event or a dom level event?

Comment: Check my edit, they may be more what you are looking for, but that is a work around. You should be able to disable to notification through chrome options. So I suspect your ChromeDriver options are not being configured properly.

Comment: Neither driver.switch_to.active_element, nor driver.switch_to.frame("Framename") are executed if I call them. It seems like Selenium is kind of frozen until Cancel is hit manually. I also added my Chrome option settings above if you want to take a look at them. How would I notice if this were a dom level event? It's definitely inside the browser and not a second window.

Comment: Pressing ESC closes the popup, but sending keys via Selenium doesn't work and since I'll run multiple instances at once, I can't use dom level commands.

Comment: the OP asking for python selenium and it seems the syntax is NOT python

Comment: I tried both of `ops.addArguments("--disable-notifications"); ops.addArguments("--disable-infobars");` but none working for me

Answer (score 0):

Either for any Person that is clicking here after years or the original user:

As far as i evaluated it is an simple authentication. So basically you need to send your username and password with it from the start:

```
https://username:password@domain
```

domain is url and can be anything. With that the basic authentication is gone and you can basically use it normally.

In Python it would be something along the lines of:

```
driver.get("https://username:password@domain")
```

Hope that helps.
At least it solved the problem i had

Comment: For the love of all that is holy, never do this. You're basically giving away your password by doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried many solutions, however the only solution that worked for me was to use the [pyautogui](https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/) package and pressing the escape key to dismiss the popup:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.press('esc')
```